# pacman -S apache VS systemctl enable httpd

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

From synthetic reading through the web on establishing an Arch-LAMP I understand that when installing Apache I should do:

```
pacman -S apache
```

and then

```
systemctl enable httpd
```

Why in the installation it's *apache* and in starting the service it's *httpd*?

<sub>Note: I have yet to rent an Arch machine, I just try to get some background before doing so.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `apache` is the package name, and short for "[Apache HTTP Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server)", the official name of the software.
- `httpd` is the "HTTP server daemon" itself, which is provided by this package. This is what the Apache Software Foundation chose to name the [daemon and related files](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/apache/files/).

Confusingly, the Apache Software Foundation themselves also use "httpd" as a short form of the [software name](https://httpd.apache.org/)

> The Apache HTTP Server ("httpd") was launched in 1995